# Why am I getting an error when using Union All and cast function?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, union-all

I'm using union all to combine different data tables together. In the last line, the `ride_length` is a string type so I decided to use the cast function to change it to a time function.

I received an error:

> Invalid time string "24:59:55"

```
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type, started_at,ended_at,ride_length,day_of_week,start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, member_casual  
 FROM `cyclistic-case-study-340816.2021_11.nov` 

 UNION ALL 
 SELECT ride_id, rideable_type, started_at,ended_at,ride_length,day_of_week,start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, member_casual  
 FROM `cyclistic-case-study-340816.2021_12.dec` 
 UNION ALL 

 SELECT ride_id, rideable_type, started_at,ended_at,CAST(ride_length AS TIME) AS ride_length,day_of_week,start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, member_casual  
 FROM `cyclistic-case-study-340816.2021_01.jan`
```

Comment: `invalid time string "24:59:55"` isn't that clear enough error message?

Comment: So is the the limit reached? I'm confused because other tables have values higher than that  (hh:mm:ss format from excel that tracked ride times of bikes) and the error message was not coming up.

Comment: range for `time` type is `00:00:00 to 23:59:59.999999` - A TIME object represents a time, as might be displayed on a watch, independent of a specific date and timezone. To represent an absolute point in time, use a timestamp. see more about [Time type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time_type) . also check [Interval type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#interval_type) - you might be referencing to it rather

Comment: I am looking to find ride length (end time - start time) in excel so I formatted the cells in 'time 37:30:55'. When I uploaded the data to big query, the cells were stored as STRING and not TIME. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: so, this explains that error - right? if you still have problem with your assignment - i recommend you to fully revisit your question and post new one with all relevant details so we can help further